# The meaning of " a hasty snatch scraped on a fiddle,"

Tags: meaning

> When Mona ran from the tinkers, they all pursued her: she heard their
>   feet behind her and even **a hasty snatch scraped on a fiddle**, and then
>   she heard a laugh from the tinker’s wife.

This is from “The Story of Mona Sheehy” by Lord Dunsany.(1939)
I can’t understand the meaning of the sentence below.

a hasty snatch scraped on a fiddle

Before the scene above, The tinkers were playing their fiddles around her.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

A [snatch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snatch) in this context is a short part of something, for example a piece of music. A **hasty snatch** would be a hurriedly-played short piece of music.

[Scrape](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrape) can mean this:

> to (cause to) rub against a surface so that slight damage or **an unpleasant noise is produced**

A violin is played by rubbing the bow against the strings: to say **scraped on a fiddle** would suggest that, in this case, the sound was not pleasant.

Comment: JavaLatte, thank you for your answer. It is so helpful!